# How to conditionally select top value per group without comparing each value?

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

The data I have looks like:

```
  Group Gene      Score     direct_count   secondary_count 
    1   AQP11    0.5566507       4               5
    1   CLNS1A   0.2811747       0               2
    1   RSF1     0.5469924       3               6
    2   CFDP1    0.4186066       1               2
    2   CHST6    0.4295135       1               3
    3   ACE      0.634           1               1
    3   NOS2     0.6345          1               1
    4   Gene1    0.7             0               1
    4   Gene2    0.61            1               0
    4   Gene3    0.62            0               1
```

I am grouping the genes by the `Group` column then selecting the best gene per group based on conditions:

1. Select the gene with the highest score if the score difference between the top scored gene and all others in the group is >0.05
2. If the score difference between the top gene and any other genes in a group is <0.05 then select the gene with a higher `direct_count` *only selecting between those genes with a <0.05 distance to the top scored gene per group*
3. If the `direct_count` is the same select the gene with the highest `secondary_count`
4. If all counts are the same select all genes <0.05 distance to each other.

Output from example looking like:

```
 Group Gene      Score     direct_count   secondary_count 
    1   AQP11    0.5566507       4               5  #highest direct_count
    2   CHST6    0.4295135       1               3  #highest secondary_count after matching direct_count
    3   ACE      0.634           1               1  #ACE and NOS2 have matching counts
    3   NOS2     0.6345          1               1
    4   Gene1    0.7             0               1  #highest score by >0.05 difference
```

Currently I try to code this with:

```
df<- setDT(df)
new_df <- df[, 
   {d = dist(Score, method = 'manhattan')
   if (any(d > 0.05)) 
     ind = which.max(d)
   else if (sum(max(direct_count) == direct_count) == 1L) 
     ind = which.max(direct_count)
   else if (sum(max(secondary_count) == secondary_count) == 1L) 
     ind = which.max(secondary_count)
   else 
     ind = which((outer(direct_count, direct_count, '==') & outer(secondary_count, secondary_count, '=='))[1, ])
   
   .SD[ind]
   }
   , by = Group]
```

However, I am struggling to adjust my first `else if` statement to account for my 2nd condition with only selecting between genes with a <0.05 distance to the top scored gene - currently it's comparing with all genes per group so even if a gene in that group has a 0.1 score but largest `count` columns its getting selected over a top scored gene at 0.7 for example if other genes in the group are 0.68 filling that <0.05 distance requirement.

Essentially I want my conditions 2 to 4 to only be considering the genes that are <0.05 distance to the top scored gene per group.

Input data:

```
structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Gene = c("AQP11", 
"CLNS1A", "RSF1", "CFDP1", "CHST6", "ACE", "NOS2", "Gene1","Gene2","Gene3"), Score = c(0.5566507, 
0.2811747, 0.5269924, 0.4186066, 0.4295135, 0.634, 0.6345, 0.7, 0.62, 0.61), direct_count = c(4L, 
0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), secondary_count = c(5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Edit:

The reason for my question is a problem with one specific group not doing as I expect:

```
  Group Gene         Score      direct_count     secondary_count
1   2    CFDP1        0.5517401        1                  62
2   2    CHST6        0.5989186        1                   6
3   2    RNU6-758P    0.5644914        0                   1
4   2    Gene1        0.5672916        0                   1
5   2    TMEM170A     0.6167083        0                   2
```

`CHST6` has the highest `direct_count` out of all genes <0.05 of the to the top scored gene in this group, yet `Gene1` is being selected.

This second example input data:

```
structure(list(Group = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Gene = c("CFDP1", 
"CHST6", "RNU6-758P", "Gene1", "TMEM170A"), Score = c(0.551740109920502, 
0.598918557167053, 0.564491391181946, 0.567291617393494, 0.616708278656006
), direct_count = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0), secondary_count = c(62, 
6, 1, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You final goal can be achieved with two different solution: with `dplyr` and with `data.table`.

You don't need any complicated `ifelse` condition.

### Solution

INPUT

```
dt <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Gene = c("AQP11", 
                                                                           "CLNS1A", "RSF1", "CFDP1", "CHST6", "ACE", "NOS2"), Score = c(0.5566507, 
                                                                                                                                         0.2811747, 0.5269924, 0.4186066, 0.4295135, 0.634, 0.6345), direct_count = c(4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), secondary_count = c(5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   3L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "data.frame"))
```

DPLYR

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter((max(Score) - Score)<0.05) %>% 
  slice_max(direct_count, n = 1) %>% 
  slice_max(secondary_count, n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   Group Gene  Score direct_count secondary_count
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl>        <int>           <int>
#> 1     1 AQP11 0.557            4               5
#> 2     2 CHST6 0.430            1               3
#> 3     3 ACE   0.634            1               1
#> 4     3 NOS2  0.634            1               1
```

DATA.TABLE

```
library(data.table)

dt <- dt[dt[, .I[(max(Score) - Score) < 0.05], by = Group]$V1]
dt <- dt[dt[, .I[direct_count == max(direct_count)], by = Group]$V1]
dt <- dt[dt[, .I[secondary_count == max(secondary_count)], by = Group]$V1]
dt
#>    Group  Gene     Score direct_count secondary_count
#> 1:     1 AQP11 0.5566507            4               5
#> 2:     2 CHST6 0.4295135            1               3
#> 3:     3   ACE 0.6340000            1               1
#> 4:     3  NOS2 0.6345000            1               1
```

---

### Your EDIT

Related to your specific issues at the end of your question: these two methods select CHST6, as you would expect according to the rules you wrote.

```r
dt <- structure(list(Group = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
               Gene = c("CFDP1", "CHST6", "RNU6-758P", "Gene1", "TMEM170A"), 
               Score = c(0.551740109920502,  0.598918557167053, 0.564491391181946, 0.567291617393494, 0.616708278656006),
               direct_count = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
               secondary_count = c(62, 6, 1, 1, 2)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
          class = c("data.table", 
                    "data.frame"))


########## DPLYR

library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter((max(Score) - Score)<0.05) %>% 
  slice_max(direct_count, n = 1) %>% 
  slice_max(secondary_count, n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 1 x 5
#>   Group Gene  Score direct_count secondary_count
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>
#> 1     2 CHST6 0.599            1               6


########## DATATABLE

library(data.table)

dt <- dt[dt[, .I[(max(Score) - Score) < 0.05], by = Group]$V1]
dt <- dt[dt[, .I[direct_count == max(direct_count)], by = Group]$V1]
dt <- dt[dt[, .I[secondary_count == max(secondary_count)], by = Group]$V1]
dt
#>    Group  Gene     Score direct_count secondary_count
#> 1:     2 CHST6 0.5989186            1               6
```